# Xcode на windows

Tags: ios, xcode

Всем привет!
Хочу переквалифицироваться в ios разработчика, и писать на xcode. Проблема в том, что нет макбука. Если какие то варианты как завалить xcode на винду, или все же лучше  купить макбук ? Прошу отвечать только людей, которые смогли поставить xcode на windows и писать программы на нем, теория не интересует)))

Answer (score 3):

Немного не по тематике, но отвечу.
Хороших варианта у Вас 3:

1. Виртуалка
2. Хакинтош.
3. Купить б/у мак(бук)

Второй вариант предпочтительнее, т.к. немного пошаманив получаете полноценный мак(бук). Сам пользуюсь ноутбуком HP ProBook 4540s. Если будете собирать стационарный, то проблем намного меньше.

Первый вариант намного проще, но даже на довольно мощных машинах добиться быстрой работы проблематично. У себя, чтоб довольно комфортно работал Xcode, виртуалка на SSD, выделяю 12 Гб оперативной памяти и 6 ядер. Если еще нужны подробности - спрашивайте.

Comment: А по мне так третий вариант - самый подходящий. Гораздо меньше проблем и совесть не мучает.

Comment: @RomanPodymov согласен, но если ограничен бюджет, то практически сходный по характеристикам ноутбук под хакинтош в несколько раз дешевле. Стационарный тоже. А однажды повозившись дальше уже спортивный интерес.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode существует и всегда существовала только для OS X, исходный код закрыт, поэтому нужна OS X.

Самый простой способ получить OS X на Windows - арендовать VPS с OS X и подключаться по удаленному рабочему столу - обычно VNC, реже RDP, получается нечто вроде TeamViewer и вот вам полноценный Mac, разве что может не быть рут-доступа (не получится ставить программы, впрочем Xcode тогда уже стоит), и если не считать того что не получится слушать аудио и т.п. Разумеется, платно - 2000-3000 рублей в месяц, но окупается одним авансом за проект, а иногда бывает, что после неуплаты не блокируют, особенно там где нет рут доступа.

Но если у вас процессор Intel, достаточно мощный, поддерживает VT-x, то можно пробовать поставить Hackintosh на жесткий диск или OS X в виртуальную машину.
Начинать лучше со старых версий, таких как 10.6 Lion, особенно если не уверены в мощности.
Если AMD, то "геморроя" гораздо больше, нужен образ с кастомным ядром. В таком случае рекомендую сперва освоить реверс-инжиниринг, чтобы все проблемы стали решаемыми хотя бы ценой N времени и N денег.